# Design: Website calling web services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I'm building a website using ASP MVC, which will need to call a webservice offering several methods like

```
int Login (string user, string password)
object GetFile(int token, string id)
```

There are 2 technical user accounts for the webservice each website user is categorized in.

How would you design the webservice calls? I thought of a singleton, but with two different credentials, this seems not so great. Any ideas?

Comment: You are right, `Singleton` is not a pattern one would use for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I think you should keep your web services as simple as possible.

Have the services merely validate information passed in (e.g. for `Login`, make sure user and password are non-zero length strings) and then pass that information into your business layer (e.g. so your `Login` web service passes user name and password to your membership class, for example, to validate the creds).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like to know, what would be the best way accessing the service. The service is given and not in my hands...

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing the service"?  Do you mean from your controller?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have the service proxy methods and I'm looking for the best way to access the service with the two service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand, but I think you are trying to consume a third-party web service?

You could persist your singleton object in a database, but I think it would be an unnecessary overhead. Or you could add the singleton to the Application. But either way, I don't think there is any need for writing a singleton.

A singleton would be a bottleneck if multiple synchronous requests to the web service are taking place. I would just create a standard Dal class to wrap the webservice with an API that your MVC app can use.